# If $T\in M_n(\mathbb{F})$ is a matrix such that $T^2=0$, then $rk(T)\le\frac{1}{2}n$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> If $T\in M_n(\mathbb{F})$ is a matrix such that $T^2=0$, then $rk(T)\le\frac{1}{2}n$.

I know that $rk(T)$ is the dimension of the subspace spanned by the vectors of $\mathbb{F}^n$ given by the columns of $T$. I just don't know how to use the fact $T^2=0$ to calculate the subspace and it's dimension.

Comment: Well, what have you tried? Just writing out the definition of rank isn't going to get you very far; what results do you know about rank that could apply here? Come on, you have to put some effort into it.

Comment: There are several ways to "jump start" solving a problem when the definition by itself doesn't immediately give the answer.  Look at some small examples.  Consider a recently presented Proposition that the exercise might have been intended to reinforce.  Analyze where your attempts to construct a counterexample seem to break down.  Etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** If $T^2 = 0$, then the image (column-space) of $T$ is contained in the kernel (null-space) of $T$.  Apply the rank-nullity theorem.