# Rank of Linear Transformation $T^2=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

let $T:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a linear transformation such that $T^2=0$ .Show that the rank ($r$) of the linear transformation obeys the inequality $r\le n/2$

Comment: What is the meaning of T^2=0

Comment: It means that $T(T(x)) = 0$ for all $x$ in $\mathbb R^n$

Comment: Or equivalently $T^2 x = 0$ for all $x$ when representing $T$ by a matrix

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2628437/81360)

Answer (score 3):

Recall the rank-nullity theorem for finite dimensional spaces
$$ \dim(\operatorname{Im}(T)) + \dim(\ker(T)) = n \ .$$
The condition $T^2 = 0$ implies that $\operatorname{Im}(T) \subset \ker(T)$. This set inclusion implies that
$$\dim(\operatorname{Im}(T)) \leq \dim(\ker(T)) \ .$$
Combining the rank-nullity theory and this inequality, we have
$$ n = \dim(\operatorname{Im}(T)) + \dim(\ker(T)) \geq 2  \dim(\operatorname{Im}(T)) \iff \dim(\operatorname{Im}(T)) \leq \frac{n}{2} \ ,$$
as desired.